# Should Telegram api_hash be kept secret?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I think I'm a bit confused about what exactly api_id and api_hash are.
I'm making a telegram client tool using telethon.
I read in telethon documentation that I should keep my api_hash secret. Is that true? But then how would I distribute my source code? By leaving the api_id and api_hash blank?
And if thats the case then I can safely use my api_id and hash in the distributed binary?

Comment: Usually if you want to share your code and you are using any type of credentials (APIs Keys, Passwords to databases) you should keep them on a separate file and then you don't give that file. (If using git you should add that file to the gitignore)

Answer (score 4):

Officially answer is **always keep it secret**.

But actually, even official Telegram client, you can obtain API ID and hash by decompile it, so it's not really have to keep secret :)

Comment: If it is possible to decompile the official client and obtain the ID, then why people create their own IDs? One can publicly share the official ID and other can use it. Isn't so?

Answer (score -1):

No way. I decompiled Telegram X because it uses tdlib and I know where to connect the debugger. After that, I searched the extracted API via google and got all the other keys.

For example official applications API
https://blb.team/threads/app-hash-app-id-oficialnyx-klientov.294/

Comment: It is unclear whether this is somehow attempting to answer the question, or just leave a comment. In the latter case, please don't use the "Post Your Answer" button to submit your comment; you will need to earn a bit of reputation and then you will see an "Add comment" link directly underneath each post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer:** You can share this data with the public. However, it is not recommended.

**Longer answer:**
Answering the direct question, if you are going to distribute your code to the public (e. g. post it on GitHub as open-source), **you are recommended to better keep it secret** as long as you do not want anyone to try to log in or send spam to the account the api_id and api_hash was obtained from.

Once anyone has your api_id and api_hash, he is able to make a request to log in into your account. So if you are uncareful, you can send the access code (which is sent to you) to the person and he will always have an access to your account.

Even though you can get this data without seeing it, by keeping it secret you avoid bigger risks and access codes spam to your account. Sharing this data will not instantly expose your account to anyone, but it is still wiser not to share it in the open-source projects.